# How to add accessibiity ID in flutter code for appium

Tags: selenium, flutter, appium

How I can add Accessibility ID in the flutter app, so that I can use it for the automation testing using appium to locate the specific element, e.g - If we have "Username" text field on the app and we want to give a unique Accessibility ID to "Username" text field.

Currently, I can see the ID while checking with appium but devs have not added the same. If anyone knows how to add ID's and share the snippet code then it would be very helpful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UajE8.png)

Comment: Did you found the answer yet?

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer for this @YashwardhanPauranik or Nimit?

Comment: @SagarKharab No. Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

We could set the `semanticsLabel` on Flutter as `Accessibility ID`. Some Flutter widgets already have `semanticsLabel`, so just need to set the value of it. For instance `Text`

```
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          semanticsLabel: 'counterText$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
        ),
```

Some others do not have it, so need to wrap it with `Semantics` widget:

```
   floatingActionButton: Semantics(
     label: 'incrementButton',
     child: FloatingActionButton(
       onPressed: _incrementCounter,
       tooltip: 'Increment',
       child: const Icon(Icons.add),
     ),
   ),
```

Here is the result from Appium inspector:
[image]
[image]

Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/imudita/appium_flutter/tree/main/e2e) for sample code.